# curl_init intermittently returns NULL

Tags: php, curl

I have recently moved servers and a PHP script that has worked for a long time no longer works. I've tracked it down to a wrapper class I have for easily doing multi-curl operations. The whole script works start to finish occasionally but fails most of the time.

However, during my testing I found that when the script failed it failed here:

```
$ch = curl_init();
```

When the script failed $ch was NULL. The documentation (php.net) says that it should return a resource on success and FALSE on failure not NULL.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 server. As I've said this script ran for a long time. So I'm thinknig one of a few things has happened. First, the image from my hosting company is supposed to be the latest with the latest security patches, etc. Could there have been a PHP patch that messed something up? Second, there's a resource issue I didn't experience on the previous machine (or any other machine I've used for that matter). Finally, there's something wrong with the image my hosting company installed.

If anyone has any experience with this type of error I'd love to hear it.

Update:

```
$ch = curl_init();
echo '<br>Res: ' . var_dump($ch);
```

Returns:

```
Res: NULL
```

Comment: Are you sure it's returning NULL? How are you printing its value? See [`curl_init()` silently returns NULL](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.php/curl_init-silently-returns-null/299307).  TL;DR: use `var_dump()`, not `var_export()`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks, I am using var_export. I tried var_dump per your suggestion and updated the question. It is still returning NULL with var_dump.

Comment: I think you've skipped the code between ``$ch = curl_init()`` and ``var_dump($ch)``. Usually the ``$ch`` is set to ``null`` from a cURL option being set wrong. Also, you said your doing "multi curl" operations. Are all the other cURL handles being closed properly? Is there enough memory?

Comment: @ub3rst4r That's what is so weird. There is no code at all btwn the curl_init and the echo and it is returning NULL. Additionally, this is a multi-curl wrapper but only 1 URL is being sent to it so this is the only resource being created. The code creates the curl resource only as needed. It has worked fine for months until I put it on this new server.

Comment: The more I look into this the more I think it is faulty hardware or a bad image. I have web pages that load and then the next time I reload them I get an empty response. I have odd WordPress plugin errors due to missing tables in the DB that shouldn't be missing. The same code runs just fine on another server...

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar problem, and my guess is that `curl_init()` is disabled in your php server, for some reason that i do not know .

Please check if `curl_init()` is enabled in your system, and please set `error-reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script to see what might be wrong.
In my case, i am receiving a warning saying that `curl_init()` is disabled for security reasons.